# Here() function doesn't change its directory after pushing the source code to github

Tags: r, factory

I am writing a Rmd file, where it contains some knitted images. The Rmd file shows stuffs just as expected when looking at them on my own computer, but it cannot show the inserted images when uploaded to my github.

To knit the inserted images, I used here() function:

```r
knitr::include_graphics(c(here("data/images/experiments_areaId2ad4/plots",  "scatter_old.png"), here("data/images/experiments_areaId2ad4/plots",  "scatter_new.png")))
```

On the github, the images cannot be shown, and as most html, there are tiny placeholders at the positions of each of the images. When I clicked on one of the place holder, it led me to a webpage that was 404.

I looked at the URL, it is like:
https://github.com/[my_github_account]/[my_github_repo]/blob/master/Users/[myname]/Desktop/[my_local_path]/[my_github_repo]/my_reports/data/images/experiments_areaId2ad4/plots/scatter_new.png

Obviously it has copied my local path from my computer to the github, so that the paths of these images are definitely not valid anymore.

However, I still want to use the here() function, so that when my collaborators pull my github updates, they can still interact with my projects without having to worry about screwing up directory.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: By the way, I am not "prestigious" enough to create a non-existing tag, but a tag named report-factory is much more appropriate than factory, and it's gonna be super  helpful for people working on report factory in the future. Could someone help me change the tag "factory" to "report-factory"? Thanks!

Comment: Where is this issue happening? Just when you look at the actual `.Rmd` file on github, or when you look at the rendered HTML file? If it's the `.Rmd` file, I'm not sure if this is fixable unless Github changes how they preview Rmd files.